# Having trouble with fork execlp and array argument

Tags: c, process, fork, exe

I'm having trouble on the outcomes of a function I have made to take in a two dimensional array and run another program which returns the correct version of each word, for example for "eerch" -> returns"cheer".
To do that fork is implemented alongside file descriptors in order to use the exe family of fynctions, the problem is that the execlp() function seems to not run properly when the argument is the array but when the argument is literal (for example "eerch") it works just fine.To clarify the words to be corrected are given by the exercise I'm tasked to solve so is the './findword' binary file, considering that everything else runs just fine and I've made sure the array contains the proper elements its just that little argument problem I am having, and all that is being operated in ubuntu.

```
#define MAX_LINE 25
int Fix(char WM[][MAX_LINE], int count )
{

int num_id,  proc_fd[count][2];

for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
if(pipe(proc_fd[i]) <  0)
{
    perror("Error could not open child Pipe array, now exiting");
    exit(-1);
}
}

if(pipe(par_fd)  < 0)
{
perror("Error could open parent pipe, now exiting");
exit(-1);
 
}

for(num_id = 0; num_id < count; num_id++ )
{   
if(fork()==0)
{   
    //CHILD PROCESS//
    int value;
    
    read(par_fd[0], &value, sizeof(value));
            
    dup2(proc_fd[num_id][1], 1);
    
    execlp("./findword", "findword", "dictionary.txt", WM[value][MAX_LINE], NULL);
    
}else
{
    //PARENT PROCESS//
    
    char buffer[MAX_LINE] = "";
    int pointer = num_id;
    printf("\nPARENT SENDS %s",WM[num_id] );
    write(par_fd[1], &pointer, sizeof(pointer));
    
    
    read(proc_fd[num_id][0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("CHILD RETURNED %s", buffer);

}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The two dimensional file descriptor is a task of the exercise.

Comment: also the format WM[value] does no work